# Get query parameters from external url and make a redirection

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect, query-variable

assuming that I have been redirected from an external API, to my front page website, and in the current url there is some query parameter provided by that API, how can I get those parameters and make a redirection to an external website, before my front page website have rendered ?
Example:

```
// This is the url returned by the external api, so it redirects users to my website

         https://mywebsite.com&redirect_uri=otherwebsite.com

// So I would like to get the redirect_uri parameter value and make a redirection to that url, like so:

              wp_redirect( $_GET[‘redirect_uri’] );
              exit;
```

The most important question here would be, which hook should I use to get all this things done ??, like I said, BEFORE my front page website get rendered. I don’t know if using $_GET is enough to get the parameter neither. So I need help, thank you!